# how does model validation work? What is needed for an appropriate validation

Tags: hydrology, models

I have an 2D hydrodynamic model in a approx. 10km² catchment and one rain event that goes one hour with measurements in a 5min interval. The reccurance interval for an event like that is close to 50years.

When I run my simulation software I get the flood heights for every m² in my catchment for every 30min. My question is, how do I validate my result? I guess, ideally I take the flood heights for 10 other rain events with the same intensity and duration and see if it fits my results. But I don't have these information.

what could be approaches to validate my model?

Comment: The usual approach is to use a simplified setting that can be solved analytically - then you compare numerical and analytical solution.

Comment: ok sounds good. Unfortunately, I don't know you mean by "analytical setting". Could you give me an example, then I can do some research for suitable analytical approaches.

Comment: I said simplified setting - You choose the equations, boundary conditions and model parameters such that you can solve the whole system on paper - then compare to the simulation. Often there are also standard benchmarks that different simulation communities have agreed upon.

Comment: There are multiple levels of model validation and verification that can be performed. Compare to an analytical model, calibrate on one time period and compare to other periods, Apply a stochastic variation based on the uncertainties in your parameters (eg using PEST). I suggest you look at the literature for similar models and see what they did.

Comment: A common method would be to run a simulation using the same starting conditions in your model and another previously published model and see how well they match

Comment: Hello Will, 

but there are no publications for my study area. But you mean I could do another simulation with another well known model and if the results are nearly the same than my model is probably representing the reality pretty good?